# Epplus formula error

Tags: c#, vb.net, epplus

I'm using Epplus to put a formula into a cell. If I put this formula manually into the Excel cell it works:

```
=SUM(E4;G4)
```

But when I put in code with Epplus it doesn't work:

```
xls.ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Formula = "SUM(E4;G4)"
```

Is there something special needed when I SUM two cells?
If I do the same with a range of cells it works, but with specific cells not.

This works (Range):

```
xls.ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Formula = "SUM(E4:G4)"
```

Comment: `doesn't work` is not specific. You need to tell us, what's not working. Is it showing the value instead of making the calculation?

Comment: You are using Dutch or some other international version. You might want to try the English notation: sum(e4,g4)

Comment: That formula does not work for me in Excel, I have to use =SUM(E4,G4)  Guido might be right, you might have different notation.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing this

```
xls.ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Formula = "SUM(E4;G4)";
```

into

```
xls.ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Formula = "SUM(E4,G4)";
```

Somehow using `;` in a formula messes things up. Could be a bug...